# How to enumerate network adapters and get their MAC addresses in Win32 API C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, ethernet, mac-address

How do I enumerate network adapters and get their MAC addresses in Win32 API C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code should work:

```
{
    ULONG outBufLen = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO* pAdapterInfos = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*) malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));

    // retry up to 5 times, to get the adapter infos needed
    for( int i = 0; i < 5 && (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW || dwRetVal == NO_ERROR); ++i )
    {
        dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfos, &outBufLen);
        if( dwRetVal == NO_ERROR )
        {
            break;
        }
        else if( dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW )
        {
            free(pAdapterInfos);
            pAdapterInfos = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*) malloc(outBufLen);
        }
        else
        {
            pAdapterInfos = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( dwRetVal == NO_ERROR )
    {
        IP_ADAPTER_INFO* pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfos;
        while( pAdapterInfo )
        {
            IP_ADDR_STRING* pIpAddress = &(pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList);
            while( pIpAddress != 0 )
            {
                          // 
                          // <<<<
                          // here pAdapterInfo->Address should contain the MAC address
                          // >>>>
                          // 

                pIpAddress = pIpAddress->Next;
            }
            pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
        }
    }
    free(pAdapterInfos);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why allocate pAdapterInfos using mallock instead of stack?

Comment: Because the buffer is larger then only that one struct. The loop updates the size parameter.

Comment: (yes, I realize this answer is old.) Can you explain how this code works in prose, rather than having a couple of comments explaining bits and pieces?

Comment: @NicHartley, where `here` is commented the required information should be fetched from `pAdapterInfo` and get stored in a list (which is an exercise left to the reader of the answer)