# Coding Trial Period in a software

Tags: c++

I am trying to introduce a feature in our team's software using which the user will not be able to use the free version of the software beyond a specific amount of time. I have seen a feature in some software in which if you try to uninstall it after trial period is over and then re-install it denies access. I want to introduce this feature as well.
1) How can I know that the software was pre-installed on a particular computer. I tried looking for this and I got to know that the **registry editor of windows** makes a note of all the installed software and has its record even after it is uninstalled. Can the registry editor help me in designing this feature. **If yes can you please tell me how can I write a code in C++ using which I can read the registery editor.**
2) Is there some other feature in one's computer which is unique to it like the MAC address which I can make a note using a C++ code.

Comment: This might be of interest while you are looking at these kind of things: http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2004/09/05/using-openssl-for-license-keys/

Comment: I wonder what your product is for and how it'll work, if you cannot get such basic things like reading from/writing to registry from MSDN or other samples. Besides, access to the registry may be simply tracked and those keys be removed. Furthermore, registry is already too polluted with data like that. Concentrate on the function of your app and only then think about copy protection.

Comment: JeffRSon: "Besides, access to the registry may be simply tracked and those keys be removed." Easier solution: Change system time to year 2099. Install software. Change system time back.

Comment: @SigTerm: Copy protection that doesn't detect the date changed backward is a waste anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do depending on what your program is 
supposed to do.
If it is **document oriented**, **remove the 'Save'** from the program so people 
can see it works, but not actually use it until they pay.
If it is **database oriented**, put a limit on the **number of records** the 
program can deal with.

During installation, or when the program run for the first time, use say the
date, time, volume number, matching tag, hard disk space etc to generate a
number and stored it in the registry. This becomes the "activation code".
When customer pays, they need to submit the number to you. You use the
number as input to you secret algorithm to generate an unlock key. The rest
is up to your imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related pages for accessing the registry.

For getting MAC address look at [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673931/how-do-i-enumerate-network-adapters-and-get-their-mac-addresses-in-win32-api-c) too.

Answer (score -1):

****You Can use the below example as a suggestion****

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Perl", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
bool bExistsAndSuccess (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS);
bool bDoesNotExistsSpecifically (lRes == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
std::wstring strValueOfBinDir;
std::wstring strKeyDefaultValue;
GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"BinDir", strValueOfBinDir, L"bad");
GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"", strKeyDefaultValue, L"bad");

LONG GetDWORDRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, DWORD &nValue, DWORD nDefaultValue)
{
    nValue = nDefaultValue;
    DWORD dwBufferSize(sizeof(DWORD));
    DWORD nResult(0);
    LONG nError = ::RegQueryValueExW(hKey,
        strValueName.c_str(),
        0,
        NULL,
        reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&nResult),
        &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        nValue = nResult;
    }
    return nError;
}


LONG GetBoolRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, bool &bValue, bool bDefaultValue)
{
    DWORD nDefValue((bDefaultValue) ? 1 : 0);
    DWORD nResult(nDefValue);
    LONG nError = GetDWORDRegKey(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), nResult, nDefValue);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        bValue = (nResult != 0) ? true : false;
    }
    return nError;
}


LONG GetStringRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, std::wstring &strValue, const std::wstring &strDefaultValue)
{
    strValue = strDefaultValue;
    WCHAR szBuffer[512];
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    ULONG nError;
    nError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        strValue = szBuffer;
    }
    return nError;
}
```

Comment: Too much code, not enough explaining. This is in danger of receiving downvotes.

Comment: The user asks for explanations, not for a piece of long code. Please read careful the questions you are answering to.