# C++ windows number of wifi adapters

Tags: c++, windows, command, wifi, system

I need to figure out the number of wifi adapters in a pc. What is the easiest way to get the number of wifi adapters in c++ code, even a system command via netsh is sufficient.
Thanks

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673931/how-to-enumerate-network-adapters-and-get-their-mac-addresses-in-win32-api-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673931/how-to-enumerate-network-adapters-and-get-their-mac-addresses-in-win32-api-c)

Comment: Also (has a answer that finds WIFI devices): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016166/check-if-windows-computer-on-ethernet-via-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016166/check-if-windows-computer-on-ethernet-via-c)

Comment: The correct and easiest way is to use WlanEnumInterfaces function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanenuminterfaces)

Comment: thanks everyone, finally decided to use WlanEnumInterfaces. @MikePetrichenko